# Searching for a list of words in XML file in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, xlm

I have this XML file that contains more than 2000 phrases, below is a small sample.

```xml
<TEXT>

<PHRASE>
<V>played</V>
<N>John</N>
<PREP>with</PREP>
<en x='PERS'>Adam</en>
<PREP>in</PREP>
<en x='LOC'> ASL school/en>
</PHRASE>

<PHRASE>
<V y='0'>went</V>
<en x='PERS'>Mark</en>
<PREP>to</PREP>
<en x='ORG>United Nations</en>
<PREP>for</PREP>
<PREP>a</PREP>
<N>visit</N>
</PHRASE>

<PHRASE>
<PREP>in</PREP>
<en x='DATE'>1987</en>
<en x='PERS'>Nick</en>
<V>founded</V>
<en x='ORG'>XYZ company</en>
</PHRASE>

<PHRASE>
<en x='ORG'>Google's</en>
<en x='PERS'>Frank</en>
<V>went</V>
<N>yesterday</N>
<PREP>to</PREP>
<en x='LOC'>San Fransisco/en>
</PHRASE>
</TEXT>
```

And I have a list of patterns:

```
 finalPatterns=['went \n to \n','created\n  the\n', 'founded\n a\n', 'went\n yesterday\n to\n', 'a\n visit\n', 'founded\n in\n']
```

What I want is to take each finalPattern for example: **went to** and search for its presence in each phrase in the text, if any phrase contains both **went** AND **to** then it print out its 2 `<en>` tags. [Not if en tags not equal to PERS & ORG nothing is printed]

**When it searches for:**

```
-"went" & "to" --> this is the output: Frank -San Fransisco
-"founded" & "in" --> output: Nick-XYZ Company
```

That's what I did but it didn't work. Nothing was printed.

```
for phrase in root.findall('./PHRASE'):
 ens = {en.get('x'): en.text for en in phrase.findall('en')}
 if 'ORG' in ens and 'PERS' in ens:
   if all(word in phrase for word in finalPatterns):
      x="".join(phrase.itertext())   #print whats in between [since I would also like to print the whole sentence]
      print("ORG is: {}, PERS is: {} /".format(ens["ORG"],ens["PERS"]))
```

Comment: Shouldn't "went"+"to" also return Mark?

Comment: You're additionally not showing all the code. What is `root`, etc.

Comment: Using newline characters to delimit the different words in each of your list entries seems odd. You could probably just use spaces or some other character if you wanted.

Comment: If I were a beginner at Python I'd avoid list comprehensions because they are so awkward to debug. There's nothing wrong with splitting them out into separate for loops, then you can print/debug to find out why things aren't working. `word in phrase for word in finalPatterns` isn't going to work because an entry in finalPatterns is e.g. 'went \n to \n' and phrase is an ElementTree Element: they will never be equal, hence no printout. You need to split each entry of finalPatterns and check each of those words against the text in <v>, <n> and <prep> subelements of phrase.

Comment: @barny I tried a lot of stuff, I just don't seem to get the hang of it, any other advices ?  
I tried replacing that line:
   if all(word in phrase for word in finalPatterns):
with
   if all(word in phrase for word in finalPatterns[0].split()): #i will iterate over all finalPatterns elements but it didn't work also

Comment: If I write it for you you won't learn much. What I posted below works, with the fixed version of your xml, and the finalPatterns you posted, and the first three lines of code you posted, with my code indented below the if. Reduce the xml data to a single phrase that should match a single finalPattern, Add some print statements so you can see what the code is doing.

Comment: Also, read the error message you are getting. Edit the question above, post your code, ALL of it (all of it that shows the problem - it shouldn't be very long, include the import statements) so I could paste it into an editor and try it myself. You might want to put the xml into a string in the code so I can see exactly the xml you are using.

Comment: `word in phrase` will always always always return False - it _can't_return True because phrase is an ElementTree Element (in a list context like this it will return the subelements, but they still aren't strings) and word is a string - that's why I created phrasewords in my code below, gathering the text from all the V, N and PREP children.  `if all(word in phrase for word in finalPatterns[0].split())` this will only try to match against the first item in finalPatterns, that's why I added the extra for loop iterating over finalPatterns in my answer below.

Comment: You have errors in your xml: `<en x='LOC'> ASL school/en>` is missing a `<` and `<en x='ORG>United Nations</en>` is missing a `'`. Run your xml through a validator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
phrasewords = [w.text for w in phrase.findall('V')+phrase.findall('N')+phrase.findall('PREP')]
for words in finalPatterns:
    if all(word in phrasewords for word in words.split()):
         print "found"
```

Comment: Did you try adding some debugging e.g. `print phrasewords`, and in the for loop `print all(word in phrasewords for word in words.split())` or `print [word in phrasewords for word in words.split()]` - this should print a list of False and True - True when a word is in the phrasewords. It works for me, although I had to create a working example from the bits you posted and added some more that you didn't post. I also had to fix the xml you posted.

Comment: This code goes below `if 'ORG' in ens and 'PERS' in ens:` Difficult, isn't it, getting something incomplete working.

Comment: it worked fine, but for some reason it printed duplicates
for phrase in root.findall('./PHRASE'):
     ens = {en.get('x'): en.text for en in phrase.findall('en')}
     if 'ORG' in ens and 'PERS' in ens:
       phrasewords = [w.text for w in phrase.findall('V')+phrase.findall('N')+phrase.findall('PREP')+phrase.findall('CONJ')+phrase.findall('ADJ')]
       for words in finalPattern:
         if all(word in phrasewords for word in words.split()):
          print("ORG is: {}, PERS is: {} /".format(ens["ORG"],ens["PERS"]))
ie: Mark-UN was printed more than once even though it occurred only once

Comment: Thanks a lot :) @barny

Comment: That's because in your finalPatterns there are sometimes two patterns which match a phrase, for example `went to` and `a visit` both match UN+Mark.

Answer (score 1):

Consider [XSLT](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt) (the special-purpose language that manipulates XML documents) in handling your search where it rewrites the original xml according to matched values.

Below XSLT is embedded in Python to dynamically remove unmatched elements using the `finalPatterns` list. From there, Python can transform (using `lxml` module) the original document, then use such output for your end use needs.

**Python** Script

```
import lxml.etree as ET

finalPatterns=['went \n to \n','created\n  the\n', 'founded\n a\n', 'went\n yesterday\n to\n', 'a\n visit\n', 'founded\n in\n']

# BUILDING XSLT FILTER STRING
contains = ''
for p in finalPatterns:
    contains += "("
    for i in p.split('\n '):
        contains += "contains(., '{}') and \n".format(i.replace('\n', '').strip(' '))    
    contains += ")"
    contains = contains.replace(' and \n)', ') or ')

xslstr = '''<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
            <xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
            <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

              <!-- Identity Transform -->
              <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
                <xsl:copy>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                </xsl:copy>
              </xsl:template>

               <!-- Rewrites Matching Phrase elements -->
               <xsl:template match="PHRASE">
                <xsl:copy>      
                  <wholetext>
                    <xsl:call-template name="join">
                      <xsl:with-param name="valueList" select="*"/>
                      <xsl:with-param name="separator" select="' '"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                  </wholetext>

                  <xsl:choose>
                      <xsl:when test="contains(., 'went') = True and contains(., 'to') = True">
                        <match>went to</match>
                      </xsl:when>
                      <xsl:when test="contains(., 'founded') = True and contains(., 'in') = True">
                        <match>founded in</match>
                      </xsl:when>
                      <xsl:when test="contains(., 'created') = True and contains(., 'the') = True">
                        <match>created the</match>
                      </xsl:when>
                      <xsl:otherwise test="contains(., 'a') = True and contains(., 'visit') = True">
                        <match>a visit</match>
                      </xsl:otherwise>
                  </xsl:choose>
                  <person><xsl:value-of select="en[@x='PERS']"/></person>
                  <organization><xsl:value-of select="en[@x='ORG']"/></organization>
                  <location><xsl:value-of select="en[@x='LOC']"/></location>
                </xsl:copy>
              </xsl:template>

              <!-- Rewrites Unmatched Phrase elements -->
              <xsl:template match="PHRASE[not({0})]"/>

              <!-- Join Text values -->
              <xsl:template name="join">
                <xsl:param name="valueList" select="''"/>
                <xsl:param name="separator" select="','"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="$valueList">
                  <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="position() = 1">
                      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                      <xsl:value-of select="concat($separator, .) "/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                  </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:for-each>
              </xsl:template>

            </xsl:transform>'''.format(contains[:-4])    

dom = ET.parse(os.path.join(cd, 'SearchWords.xml'))
xslt = ET.fromstring(xslstr)

transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
newdom = transform(dom)

tree_out = ET.tostring(newdom, encoding='UTF-8', pretty_print=True)
print(tree_out.decode("utf-8"))

for phrase in newdom.findall('PHRASE'):    
    print("Text: {} \n ORG is: {}, PERS is: {} /".format(phrase.find('wholetext').text,
                                                         phrase.find('organization').text,
                                                          phrase.find('person').text))
```

**Output**

Below includes transformed xml for demonstration. The `tree_out` string can be saved externally as a new xml file.

```
<TEXT>
  <PHRASE>
    <wholetext>went Mark to United Nations for a visit</wholetext>
    <person>Mark</person>
    <organization>United Nations</organization>
    <location/>
  </PHRASE>
  <PHRASE>
    <wholetext>in 1987 Nick founded XYZ company</wholetext>
    <person>Nick</person>
    <organization>XYZ company</organization>
    <location/>
  </PHRASE>
  <PHRASE>
    <wholetext>Google's Frank went yesterday to San Fransisco</wholetext>
    <person>Frank</person>
    <organization>Google's</organization>
    <location>San Fransisco</location>
  </PHRASE>
</TEXT>

Text: went Mark to United Nations for a visit 
 ORG is: United Nations, PERS is: Mark /
Text: in 1987 Nick founded XYZ company 
 ORG is: XYZ company, PERS is: Nick /
Text: Google's Frank went yesterday to San Fransisco 
 ORG is: Google's, PERS is: Frank /
```

---

**List Comprehension**

See list comprehension attempt using `xpath`. However, the challenge is your `finalPatterns` does not match on congruous matches. For instance text may use `went \n to` with words in between like `went \n Mark \n to`. If you only include one keyword per element of the list, then below can work. Otherwise consider [regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) for pattern recognition.

```
dom = ET.parse(os.path.join(cd, 'Input.xml'))

phraselist = dom.xpath('//PHRASE')    
for phrase in phraselist:    
    if any(word in p for p in phrase.xpath('./*/text()') for word in finalPatterns):
        print(' '.join(phrase.xpath('./*/text()')))
        print('ORG is: {0}, PERS is: {1}'.format(phrase.xpath("./en[@x='ORG']")[0].text, \
                                                 phrase.xpath("./en[@x='PERS']")[0].text))
```

Comment: But the thing is that 'finalPatterns' is automatically generated, and it contains 24 patterns, I just wrote it here like that for simplicity. So does that mean that I will have to write the 24 patterns in the XSLT file ??

I was hoping that there some pythonic way to simply do it

Comment: You could dynamically create the xslt string as it can be embedded inside Python to take items in `finalPatterns`. See edit. I also include a list comprehension attempt with xpath with a caveat on searching in `finalPatterns`.